# Problem with remote nodes after ros packages upgrade

Tags: ros, roslaunch, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Last June 6 I performed the available upgrade of ros packages, and now I'm experiencing an strange problem: using the same roslaunch files I had now the nodes in remote machines (for me those responsible for robot I/O) doesn't start up. They bring up when using a local launch file, so maybe this is an issue with roslaunch?

Now I've checked that they actually start up, but then die inmediately after.

I changed nothing in my launch files, so I was wondering wether this was an issue of the upgrade in the ros_comm stack

Thank you in advance for your comments

Carlos

I'm using diamondback in Ubuntu 10.04, and here I list the ros packages I updated through Synaptic:

```
Commit Log for Mon Jun  6 10:11:25 2011
Upgraded the following packages:
ros-diamondback-camera-drivers (1.4.1-s1299038009~lucid) to 1.4.1-s1306620563~lucid
ros-diamondback-common (1.4.3-s1299027615~lucid) to 1.4.3-s1306609639~lucid
ros-diamondback-common-msgs (1.4.0-s1299027519~lucid) to 1.4.0-s1306609559~lucid
ros-diamondback-common-tutorials (0.1.2-s1299053657~lucid) to 0.1.2-s1306638686~lucid
ros-diamondback-control (0.1.1-s1299033115~lucid) to 0.1.1-s1306616386~lucid
ros-diamondback-desktop-full (1.0.0-s1304391878~lucid) to 1.0.0-s1306677492~lucid
ros-diamondback-diagnostics (1.4.0-s1299028141~lucid) to 1.4.0-s1306609964~lucid
ros-diamondback-diagnostics-monitors (1.4.0-s1299038404~lucid) to 1.4.0-s1306621047~lucid
ros-diamondback-documentation (1.4.1-s1299054311~lucid) to 1.4.1-s1306639612~lucid
ros-diamondback-driver-common (1.2.3-s1299028246~lucid) to 1.2.3-s1306610051~lucid
ros-diamondback-erratic-robot (0.2.0-s1304359692~lucid) to 0.2.0-s1306635164~lucid
ros-diamondback-executive-smach (1.0.1-s1299034118~lucid) to 1.0.1-s1306617318~lucid
ros-diamondback-executive-smach-visualization (1.0.1-s1299051085~lucid) to 1.0.1-s1306636595~lucid
ros-diamondback-geometry (1.4.1-s1299027775~lucid) to 1.4.2-s1306609794~lucid
ros-diamondback-geometry-experimental (0.1.4-s1299035647~lucid) to 0.1.5-s1306618067~lucid
ros-diamondback-geometry-tutorials (0.1.3-s1299042659~lucid) to 0.1.3-s1306625345~lucid
ros-diamondback-image-common (1.4.1-s1299029638~lucid) to 1.4.1-s1306610124~lucid
ros-diamondback-image-pipeline (1.4.1-s1302036824~lucid) to 1.4.2-s1306619150~lucid
ros-diamondback-image-transport-plugins (1.4.1-s1302032693~lucid) to 1.4.1-s1306610938~lucid
ros-diamondback-joystick-drivers (1.4.1-s1301689512~lucid) to 1.4.1-s1306611037~lucid
ros-diamondback-kinect (0.1.6-s1302037168~lucid) to 0.1.6-s1306620703~lucid
ros-diamondback-kinematics (0.3.3-s1304034970~lucid) to 0.3.3-s1306615328~lucid
ros-diamondback-laser-drivers (1.2.2-s1299041777~lucid) to 1.2.2-s1306624585~lucid
ros-diamondback-laser-pipeline (1.2.0-s1299027967~lucid) to 1.2.0-s1306612505~lucid
ros-diamondback-motion-planners (0.3.9-s1304352571~lucid) to 0.3.9-s1306615697~lucid
ros-diamondback-motion-planning-common (0.3.6-s1304034571~lucid) to 0.3.6-s1306615012~lucid
ros-diamondback-motion-planning-environment (0.3.1-s1298601768~lucid) to 0.3.1-s1306619083~lucid
ros-diamondback-motion-planning-visualization (0.3.1-s1298607902~lucid) to 0.3.1-s1306625171~lucid
ros-diamondback-navigation (1.4.1-s1301523272~lucid) to 1.4.1-s1306612684~lucid
ros-diamondback-openni-kinect (0.1.3-s1302657579~lucid) to 0.2.1-s1306611764~lucid
ros-diamondback-orocos-toolchain-ros (0.3.2-s1304497659~lucid) to 0.3.2-s1306628274~lucid
ros-diamondback-perception-pcl (0.10.0-s1299028346~lucid) to 0.10.0-s1306611175~lucid
ros-diamondback-physics-ode (1.4.0-s1298593424~lucid) to 1.4.1-s1306612903~lucid
ros-diamondback-point-cloud-perception (0.5.2-s1299038145~lucid) to 0.5.2-s1306619711~lucid
ros-diamondback-pr2-cockpit (0.3.1-s1302040132~lucid) to 0.3.1-s1306634810~lucid
ros-diamondback-pr2-common (1.4.4-s1299032909~lucid) to 1.4.5-s1306616195~lucid
ros-diamondback-pr2-controllers (1.4.0-s1299033347~lucid) to 1.4.0-s1306616592~lucid
ros-diamondback-pr2-ethercat-drivers (1.4.1-s1299037723~lucid) to 1.4.1-s1306622130~lucid
ros-diamondback-pr2-mechanism (1.4.4-s1299033195~lucid) to 1.4.4-s1306616451~lucid
ros-diamondback-pr2-simulator (1.4.3-s1302038183~lucid) to 1.4.3-s1306623403~lucid
ros-diamondback-robot-model (1.4.0-s1299029173~lucid) to 1.4.0-s1306611922~lucid
ros-diamondback-ros (1.4.6-s1298587598~lucid) to 1.4.8-s1306608830~lucid
ros-diamondback-ros-comm (1.4.5-s1299027150~lucid) to 1.4.6-s1306609281~lucid
ros-diamondback-ros-realtime (0.5.1-s1299044295~lucid) to 0.5.1-s1306633260~lucid
ros-diamondback-ros-tutorials (0.2.4-s1299042529~lucid) to 0.2.4-s1306625227~lucid
ros-diamondback-rx (1.4.1-s1299029758~lucid) to 1.4.1-s1306613200~lucid
ros-diamondback-simulator-gazebo (1.2.8-s1299040501~lucid) to 1.2.8-s1306622600~lucid
ros-diamondback-simulator-stage (1.2.4-s1299041907~lucid) to 1.2.5-s1306640478~lucid
ros-diamondback-slam-gmapping (1.2.2-s1301690889~lucid) to 1.2.2-s1306617388~lucid
ros-diamondback-trajectory-filters (0.3.3-s1304352350~lucid) to 0.3.3-s1306615498~lucid
ros-diamondback-vision-opencv (1.4.2-s1302031196~lucid) to 1.4.3-s1306610230~lucid
ros-diamondback-visualization (1.4.1-s1303841303~lucid) to 1.4.1-s1306614471~lucid
ros-diamondback-visualization-common (1.4.0-s1299029955~lucid) to 1.4.1-s1306613399~lucid
ros-diamondback-visualization-tutorials (0.2.2-s1299054203~lucid) to 0.2.2-s1306639510~lucid
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10195/problem-with-remote-nodes-after-ros-packages-upgrade/) by [chcorbato](https://answers.ros.org/users/305/chcorbato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2011-06-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chcorbato](https://answers.ros.org/users/305/chcorbato/) on 2011-06-09**:
But I did not change any of that configuration. All that changed was upgrade the ros packages. And downgrading them back solved the issue. I agree it is probably not roslaunch as you argue, but maybe some issue with the master?

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-06-09**:
All implications are that this is a networking issue of some sort, unrelated to roslaunch as the roslaunch processes come up and down correctly.  It seems more likely it's a change in a ROS_MASTER_URI, ROS_IP, or some other network configuration as the nodes are having issues contacting the master.

**Comment by [chcorbato](https://answers.ros.org/users/305/chcorbato/) on 2011-06-09**:
Thank you anyway, I checked what you said  :-)

**Comment by [chcorbato](https://answers.ros.org/users/305/chcorbato/) on 2011-06-09**:
I don't think it is a network problem, I can ssh from one machine to the other and roslaunch does it: as I said, even killing the roslaunch process in my desktop computer terminates the remote nodes processes in the remote robot computer. The issue is that they do not appear as ROS nodes

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-09**:
Maybe its a networking problem? Can you check if each machine can ping the master and vice-versa using the hostname of the machine (not its IP). You can try to set ROS_IP on each machine (to its ip).

**Comment by [chcorbato](https://answers.ros.org/users/305/chcorbato/) on 2011-06-08**:
I do not get any errors from roslaunch. Apparently the nodes get disconnected from master, since #rosnode list does not list, but the their processes are still there. Surprisingly killing the roslaunch process in the base machine kills them in the remote ones!

**Comment by [chcorbato](https://answers.ros.org/users/305/chcorbato/) on 2011-06-08**:
I do not get any errors from roslaunch. Apparently the nodes start up, but then die immediately afterwards.  When I do # rosnode list, they are not there. I know they start because one communicates with my robot, and I get the initialization beeps.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-06-08**:
Can you post the error messages you get from roslaunch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like it is an issue with the upgrades in the lucid packages last June 6.
I managed to reinstall my ROS installation from the packages in my /var/cache/apt directory and now roslaunch is back working as expected

---

Originally posted by [chcorbato](https://answers.ros.org/users/305/chcorbato/) with karma: 202 on 2011-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0